# AndroidAccountManager design pattern for multiple activities

Tags: android, google-api

I have multiple activities that require AndroidAccountManager...

What is the strategy/design pattern to have the login/token expire handling/pick account dialog in one place?

All the examples that google provide seem to only solve the scenario where there is only one activity.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can place the logic interacting with the AndroidAccountManager within an IntentService.

```
public class MyAuthService extends IntentService {
  ...
}
```

Remember to update your AndroidManifest.xml to declare your new service, and INIT_AUTH_REQUEST in the intent-filter:

Your Activity can then call startService(new Intent(INIT_AUTH_REQUEST)).